# Automatically apply blending mode to raster

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, style, qml

Currently using QGIS 2.18.24, but tested this on 2.14.18 as well.

I'm trying to load a QML file for a raster with a specific blending mode ('multiply'), however QGIS only applies it *until* I click 'Apply' or 'Okay', after which point it resets back to 'normal'.

I have also tested out the QgsRasterLayer().setBlendMode(6) within python, to no avail.

Is this a known bug, or am I just doing something incorrectly?

Edit: Here is some sample code:

```
# Apply style layer and set blending mode

layer = QgsRasterLayer(lr)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
layer.loadNamedStyle("Path\To\Style.qml")
layer.setBlendMode(6)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: The issue seemed to be that I was saving out the final map as a PDF, which didn't honor the blending. It works when saving out as a TIF

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be that I was saving out the final map as a PDF, which didn't honor the blending. It works when saving out as a TIF